# "Page Not Found" - is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> 404 - Page Not Found

Every time I see this error message, I think: is it grammatically correct? Because I have the feeling that the verb is missing.

Comment: It is not intended to be a grammatically correct sentence. Compare it with any of various road signs such as "Lane ends merge right" or "no thru street".

Comment: Where brevity is felt to be needed, the verb is often the first thing to go.

Comment: @AndrewLeach don't you mean "brevity needed: verb gone"?

Comment: If brevity no verb.